# JW player 6 cross domain access denied

Tags: jwplayer, cross-domain-policy

I have a HLS stream that can be viewed on an iPhone but not on a desktop. It returns the error "`Cannot load M3U8: crossdomain access denied`" message, but I have `crossdomain.xml` placed on wowza server from where stream is coming.
I am using premium edition of JW player 6 (by long tails)
Embed code for jw player is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer("video").setup({
file:"http://X.X.X.X/xxxxxxxx/mystream/playlist.m3u8",
height: 369,
width: 655,
autostart: true});
</script>
```

Comment: could you also add in the code and settings of your implementation..?

Comment: Since you have premium edition of JW player 6, maybe you can contact their support directly?

Comment: Do you also have a link?